# Explain increment operator

Tags: c++

Why is the value of i = 11 and j = 10 after running the code ?

```
 #include<iostream>
 int main()
 {
      //Put your code here
      int i = 10;
      int j = i++;
      std::cout << i << "\n";
      std::cout << j << "\n";

      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Because when the line int j = i++; j is equal to i which is 10, and then the increment operator takes place after that execution, making i 11; If you did int j = ++i, both would be 11

Comment: i++ is post-increment. Only after the line is executed does the value of i change. ++i is pre-increment and returns the incremented value straight away.

Comment: It helps to read about those operators (post/pre incrementation/decrementation). You will have a better understanding.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = 10;
```

Initializes `i` as 10.

```
int j = i++;
```

Initializes `j = i;` (`j = 10`) and the *post-increment* is applied as a *side-effect* after the expression is evaluated, making `i = 11;` before the `std::cout << i << "\n";` statement is reached.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens: i = 10;    j=10;    i++;

You assing j valor before increassing i valor.

Answer (score 0):

```
int j = i++;
```

It's the `post-increment` operator. It copies the old value of `i`, that is before `i` is incremented. So before the increment, `i` contains `10`. So `10` will be copied into `j`, and then `i`'s value will increase by `1`. It all happens in one line. So when you print out the value of `j` in the next line, `j` becomes `10` and `i` becomes `11` with updated value.

```
int j = ++i;
```

This one is the `pre-increment operator`. The only difference it has with the previous one is that the new value of `i` is copied into `j` (meaning, i is incremented first and then `j=i` assignment occurs). This will print `11` for both `i` and `j` if you print it out in the next line.